# Reverse voltage protect circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, short-circuit, circuit-protection

I am trying to add a reverse voltage protection circuit to my circuit. I searched for some circuits and simulated them with an online simulator (Circuit Simulator Applet).
It might work as I need it, but I'm not sure how it works when I invert the input voltage.

[image: Normal]

[image: Reverse]

[image]

Comment: https://www.circuits.dk/reverse-current-battery-protection-circuits/

Comment: I am wondering what's the use of zener diode when I invert the input voltage